# Frame size, propagation delay and bandwidth relationship

Tags: delay, frame, ethernet, bandwidth, data-link-layer

I found in some forum this formula for calculating the frame size in function of the propagation delay and the bandwidth : `frame size >= 2*(propagation delay)*bandwidth`, I could not however find any reliable reference either to a book or a paper that mention such a formula. Is this formula correct ? If yes could anyone please explain the logic behind? In fact, before that I always thought `frame size = propagation delay*bandwidth`.